# Drawing Directed Graph (Diagram for State Transition Matrix)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Just getting started with TikZ, and the first graph that came to mind was this one on my homework:
[image]

Can someone help me set up a general example graph and some ideas on how to:

- Label the elements in the graph (e.g. the FB, YT inscriptions are inside the points)
- Label the edges and direct the edge labels to certain sides (e.g 0.4 and 0.6 are to the left, 0.3, 0.2 are to the top)
- Adjust the curvature and angle of the edges

Thanks!

Comment: Chapter 3 in the TikZ/PGF manual starting on page 50 in version 3.1.8b has an example similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that figure has drawn in TikZ. Try `[bend left=50]` to adjust the curvature and angle of the edges (the default `[bend left]` means `[bend left=30]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{3.5} 
% \path[nodes={circle,draw,fill=yellow!50,minimum size=18mm}]
\path[nodes={circle,draw}]
(0,0)   node (I) {Instagram}        
(\a,0)  node (W) {Work}
(0,\a)  node (F) {Facebook}
(\a,\a) node (Y) {YouTube}
;
\begin{scope}[-latex]
\draw (I) to node[above]{$0.4$} (W);
\draw (F) to node[below left]{$0.3$} (W);
\draw (Y) to node[right]{$0.2$} (W);
\draw (Y) to[loop right] node{$0.6$} ();
\draw (W) to[loop right] node{$1$} ();
\draw (I) to[loop left]  node{$0.6$} ();
\draw (F) to[loop left]  node{$0.4$} ();

% try [bend left=50]. Default [bend left] means [bend left=30] 
\draw (F) to[bend left]  node[above]{$0.3$} (Y);
\draw (Y) to[bend left]  node[above]{$0.2$} (F);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In case you want the same size for Facebook, Youtube, Instagram, Work, just use

```
\path[nodes={circle,draw,fill=yellow!50,minimum size=18mm}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge,
                   cells={nodes={circle, draw=gray,
                                 minimum size=4.4em, inner sep=1pt, font=\small}},
                   every arrow/.append style = {-Latex, semithick}
                   ]
\mathrm{Facebook}
    \ar[out=210, in=150, looseness=5, "0.4"]
    \ar[r,bend left,"0.3"]
    \ar[dr,"0.3" ']    
        & \mathrm{YouTube}
            \ar[out=30,in=330,looseness=5,"0.6"]
            \ar[l,bend left,"0.2"] 
            \ar[d,"0.3"]                        \\   
\mathrm{Instagram}
    \ar[out=210,in=150,looseness=5,"0.5"]
    \ar[r,"0.4"]
        & \mathrm{Work}
            \ar[out=30,in=330,looseness=5,"1"] 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]